# Adding drag and drop support in a custom TreeView

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview, vscode-extensions

I have successfully populated a `TreeView` via creating a `TreeDataProvider` and customized the icons and its collapse-able property. Now I want to be able to drag and drop its `ViewItem`(s) onto a WebView. There are unfortunately no samples for drag and drop. Reading through the `TreeView` source, `ViewItem`(s) are created in `HeightMap.OnInsertItems()` via the `TreeView.createViewItem()`, from the derived class.

The `public TreeView.onInsertItem()` would appear to be a great extension point, extending `TreeView` and `onInsertItem()` and capturing its `ViewItem` parameter. This Unfortunately, the creation of the concrete class, `ExtHostTreeView`, that is ultimately created, is buried in layers of private methods (`createExtHostTreeViewer()`).

Strangely, the `ViewItem` has a setter for draggable. However, how would you ever get a reference to the `ViewItem` to set it? If there is a way to do this please point me at an example. If there is not, I would be glad to fork and implement it. Leaving the existing `onInsertItem` and perhaps add an array of handlers to be added to with an `addOnInsertItemListener()` method? Or perhaps use RxJS?

There are so many places this could be used. You could drag template fragments into documents or code, DSL rules into a expert system, configuration file values into parameters or right hand values (generating the code to retrieve the value). Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that drag and drop in custom views is currently not supported. There's a (fairly popular) feature request for it here:

[Add drag and drop for contributed tree views (#32592)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32592)

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.66 (March 2022) there is a [TreeDragAndDropController](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_tree-drag-and-drop-api) which can be used for some drag & drop actions.

In April 2022, their sample focuses on drag & drop within a tree view: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/tree-view-sample/src/testViewDragAndDrop.ts

It is also possible to use the `text/url-list` type as described in the documentation to allow for dragging files to the editor panel: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/dc2f5d8dd1790ac4fc6054e11b44e36884caa4be/src/vscode-dts/vscode.d.ts#L9843-L9859

It is not clear to me yet whether it is possible to drag arbitrary data to webviews or to use standard HTML5 drag & drop API in a webview to allow dragging data to a custom tree view.