# Drag & drop in custom tree view

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to support drag&drop on a custom tree view provided by a vscode extension? In my extension I use the tree view to list objects stored in a cloud service, and I'd like to allow users to simply drag and drop a file on the tree view to start the upload process.

Comment: This has already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716794/accessing-viewitem-in-a-treeview/51717517#51717517 - doesn't look like the feature request has been addressed in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks @Gama11. I'll close this question as a duplicate then.

Comment: For those finding this there is a new API in March 2022 release that begins to provide a way to support drag & drop in tree views - I don't know if this specific use case is possible: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_tree-drag-and-drop-api